# PhpStorm terminal jumps from external monitor to default on focus, mac os x

Tags: macos, phpstorm, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors: my notebook monitor, and primary big dell monitor. PhpStorm 9.02 and MacOS X 10.10.5.

When I work at PhpStorm, I move my terminal window to secondary notebook display, and when I focus PhpStorm or terminal, terminal jumps to primary monitor. When I work with 1 tab of terminal everything looks fine after switching on Pinned mode and Floating mode at terminal settings. But today I open 3 tabs, and terminal starts jumps again.

It's very annoying when you often switch between browser and PhpStorm.

Do somebody have the same problem and fix for it?

Answer (score 1):

Known bug, please vote for [IDEA-116096](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116096).
See also the corresponding JDK issue:
http://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8069154

Answer (score 0):

Please look @lena answer and vote for issue at intellij.

I found solution thats help me to avoid terminal window jumping:

1. Create new tabs in terminal.
2. Drag it to secondary display, so they become separate window.
3. Close main terminal window.

Child tabs don't jumps between displays.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing a setting in mission control. 
Just uncheck the 'Displays have separate spaces' option.

1. Go to System Preferences.
2. Click on Mission Control.
3. Uncheck the box marked Displays have separate spaces.
4. Log out an login in again.